# How to merge yearly data to monthly data with 6 months lag?

Tags: r

Yearly data (replicate 12 times):

`firm     date1      x
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5
 1        2000       5`

Monthly data:

`firm     date2      y
 1        200001     3
 1        200002     7
 1        200003     2
 1        200004     8
 1        200005     9
 1        200006     3
 1        200007     6
 1        200008     2
 1        200009     7
 1        200010     2
 1        200011     3
 1        200012     8`

How can I merge the yearly data to the monthly data with 6 months lag (merge the first month of yearly data to the monthly data of 200007, and merge the second month of yearly data to the monthly data of 200008)?

Expected outcome:

`firm      date1     date2      x       y
 1         2000      200007
 1         2000      200008
 1         2000      200009
 1         2000      200010
 1         2000      200011
 1         2000      200012
 1         2000      200101
 1         2000      200102
 1         2000      200103
 1         2000      200104
 1         2000      200105
 1         2000      200106
 1         2001      200107`

Comment: Can you write the expected output?

Comment: @Bram, I've provided the expected output, thanks

Comment: Why don't you just delete the first 6 observations and then `cbind`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
year<-data.frame("firm"=c(1,1,1,1), date1=c(2000,2000,2000,2000),x=c(5,5,5,5)) #Yearly dn
month<-data.frame("firm"=c(1,1,1,1), date2=c(200001,200002,200003,200004),y=c(3,7,2,8)) #Monthly db

month$date1<-substr(month$date2,1,4) #Create a common key between two dataframes

    merge(year[!duplicated(year),],month,by.x="date1",by.y="date1",all.x=T)
  date1 firm.x x firm.y  date2 y
1  2000      1 5      1 200001 3
2  2000      1 5      1 200002 7
3  2000      1 5      1 200003 2
4  2000      1 5      1 200004 8
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to add another column to the first dataframe in proper date format.  Here's one `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df <- df %>% 
         mutate(new_date = date1*10000 + row_number()*100 + 1,
         new_date = ymd(new_date),
         join_date = new_date + months(6), 
         join_date = year(join_date)*100 + month(join_date))
```

Then you'll want to merge the two dataframes using `join_date` and `date2`